# Extract multiple numbers between parenthesis & puts each into a list one by one

Tags: python, parsing

I am writing python codes to extract multiple numbers between parenthesis in a series of input at the same time in a .txt file, such as

```
4(12)(52.17%)
7(11)(57.899%)
5(11)(84.629%)
4(5)(29.41%)
6(15)(42.86%)
5(8)(61.54%)
```

and it is hoped to extract `12`, `11`, `11`, `5`, `15`, `8` and puts each into a list one by one. The trick is there must be space or next line between data as shown above.

Next I am writing python codes to receive multiple times between spaces in a series of input at once, such as

```
06-23 16:15
06-23 16:00
06-23 15:45
06-23 15:30
```

and puts each into a list one by one.

The codes written so far is shown below, I wonder how i could modify it to receive a series of input at once. Using functions such as regex, extact is not allowed.

```py
import pyautogui, time
from datetime import date
import openpyxl
row=1
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("data.xlsx")
ws=wb['Sheet1']
today = date.today()
Cyear=str(today.year)
XQ=[]
Month = input ("Which time do you investigate?")
Lower = input ("Please input numbers")

y=Lower[Lower.find("(")+1:Lower.find(")")]
XQ=XQ+[int(y)]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is *re* not allowed when it's the best tool for the job?

Comment: because python functions has limitations for further data manipulation.

Comment: @Momoko What limitations?

Comment: I have read some examples that inconsistence may appear if results of functions are uesd for further data manipulation, but i can not remember at the moment sorry.

Comment: So basically the foundation of your argument is a vague story you can barely remember. In that case, just use `re` because it is indeed the best solution for your problem: `re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', string)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this, using slicing (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) and grab what you need:

```
li = ["7(11)(57.899%)", "5(11)(84.629%)", "4(5)(29.41%)"]
print(li)
for l in li:
    tmp_extract = l[2:4]
    if ")" in tmp_extract:
        tmp_extract = tmp_extract[0:1]
    print(tmp_extract)

['7(11)(57.899%)', '5(11)(84.629%)', '4(5)(29.41%)']
11
11
5
```

Comment: What if there's more than one character before the first round bracket?

Comment: @DarkKnight, I suggested a strategy for a possible solution, I did not consider every scenario.  But as mentioned "such as 4(12)(52.17%)" , I would assume the string is not random or dynamic, but on the same format every time. If we were to consider every permutation of every possible string in the universe, the question should be asked differently. And yes, one would need exception handling, different strategy (import re) and more for such a question. I agree. But he said "Using regex function is not allowed."

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `itertools` magic:

```py
from itertools import islice, dropwhile, takewhile

def get_first_parenthesized_number(string):
  from_first_opening_parenthesis = islice(
    dropwhile(lambda char: char != '(', string),
    1, None
  )
  until_next_closing_parenthesis = takewhile(
    lambda char: char != ')',
    from_first_opening_parenthesis
  )
  
  return int(''.join(until_next_closing_parenthesis))
```

First, `dropwhile()` drops every leading character that is not a `(`, not including the first `(`. `islice()` then takes what it returns and drop the `(` itself. Next, `takewhile()` takes everything until, but not including, the next `)`. Finally, we join whatever we just got and parse those as an `int`.

Try it:

```py
testcases = [
  '4(12)(52.17%)',
  '7(11)(57.899%)',
  '5(11)(84.629%)',
  '4(5)(29.41%)',
  '6(15)(42.86%)',
  '5(8)(61.54%)'
]

for testcase in testcases:
  print(get_first_parenthesized_number(testcase))

'''
12
11
11
5
15
8
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from the question how the data are presented so let's assume they are in a flat file.

File contents:

```
4(12)(52.17%)
7(11)(57.899%)
5(11)(84.629%)
4(5)(29.41%)
6(15)(42.86%)
5(8)(61.54%)
```

So...

```
numbers: list[int] = []

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        if (p1 := line.find('(')+1) > 0:
            if (p2 := line.find(')', p1)) > p1:
                numbers.append(int(line[p1:p2]))

print(numbers)
```

**Output:**

```
[12, 11, 11, 5, 15, 8]
```

Comment: yes it reads from .txt file, thank you

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you tell me what does p1,  p2 stand for? thank you.

Comment: @Momoko p1 and p2 are arbitrary variable names